# If the server response is false, take user back to the home component

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, scadalts

I have a REST API call `http://localhost/api/auth/isLogged/{username}`. It returns information from the server side, if given user is logged or not.

Is there any way to connect that server response with `routing` file in Angular?

My `routing.ts` file:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'app', component: AppComponent},

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

I would like to let user be able to navigate over the page if the response is `true`. If it returns `false`, I would like to take user back to the login component and make him unable to navigate over the components.

Should I add some `if` condition? Let's say that the response is saved inside 
`isLogged` boolean variable. Looking forward for any hints. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: you can use concept of gaurd: http://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/